# How to improve this loop to group objects based on one field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to improve my code a little bit but not sure if it is even possible.

I have sqlalchemy model which contains fields like `category, name, img_path`.

After I fetch all of the objects, I need to group them into categories to get the following result:
`[{"category":"some category", "skills":[{"name": "some name", "img_path":"some path"}...]}...]`

currently it looks like this:

```
skills = db.query(model.Skill).order_by(model.Skill.category).all()
```

```
    _categories = {}
    for skill in skills:
        if skill.category not in _categories:
            _categories[skill.category] = []
        _categories[skill.category].append(
            {"name": skill.name, "img_path": skill.img_path}
        )
```

It works but I believe it might be more elegant

It would be nice to have some hints how to improve this code

Comment: As your code is working, your question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Your starting code is already pretty good, one thing you could improve is using defaultdict(list) instead of plain dict, which will take care of initializing empty list for new categories, e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

_categories = defaultdict(list)

for skill in skills:
    _categories[skill.category].append(
        {"name": skill.name, "img_path": skill.img_path}
    )
```